# android canvas paint circle with glow animation

Tags: java, android, canvas

i want to make a circle (called core) glow with an animation effect like switching from bright to low glow. When i use the paint.setShadow method all the things on my canvas get a glow instead of just the core circle. How can i apply it to just the core?

```js
package com.mickvdijke.circles;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.*;

import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.res.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.app.*;

import com.mickvdijke.circles.framework.Game;
import com.mickvdijke.circles.framework.Screen;


public class GameScreen extends Screen {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
 World world;

 Paint paint = new Paint();
 RectF rect = new RectF();

 GradientDrawable gradient;

 Context r;
        
    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
  r = (Context) game;
  world = new World(game); 
  world.renew();
  rect.top = world.core.coords.y - world.core.shieldRadius;
  rect.left = world.core.coords.x - world.core.shieldRadius;
  rect.bottom = world.core.coords.y + world.core.shieldRadius;
  rect.right = world.core.coords.x + world.core.shieldRadius;

  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(0.0F);
  
  // This gradient looks quite smooth, but not perfect
  gradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR,
    new int[]{0xff001319, 0xff013e3f});
  gradient.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
  gradient.setGradientRadius((int) world.offScreenRadius);
  gradient.setDither(false);
  gradient.setGradientCenter(0.5F, 0.5F);
  gradient.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, game.getGraphics().getWidth(),
        game.getGraphics().getHeight()));
  
  paint.setTextSize(((float)game.getGraphics().getHeight()) / 16F);
  paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
  world.update(deltaTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void present(float deltaTime) {
    Canvas c = game.getGraphics().getCanvas();    
 gradient.draw(c);
 paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
 if(world.core.shieldEnergy > 0.0F)
 {
  paint.setColor(0xff003cca);
  paint.setAlpha((int) (80.0F +
        (255.0F - 80.0F) * world.core.shieldEnergy));
  c.drawCircle(world.core.coords.x, world.core.coords.y,
   world.core.shieldRadius, paint);
  paint.setAlpha(255);
 }
 paint.setColor(0xffea2533);
    paint.setShadowLayer(30, 0, 0, Color.RED);
        c.drawCircle(world.core.coords.x, world.core.coords.y,
                world.core.maxRadius * world.core.health,
                paint);
 paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 paint.setColor(0xffffffff);
 paint.setStrokeWidth(Core.SHIELD_WIDTH);
 c.drawArc(rect, (360.0F - world.core.angle),
   (360.0F - world.core.GAP_ANGLE), false, paint);
 paint.setStrokeWidth(0.0F);
 paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
 Iterator<Dot> iterator = world.dots.iterator();
 while(iterator.hasNext())
 {
  int color = 0;
  Dot dot = iterator.next();
  if(dot.type == Dot.Type.Enemy)
   color = 0xffe2192e;
  else if(dot.type == Dot.Type.Health)
   color = 0xff19dbe2;
  else if(dot.type == Dot.Type.Shield)
   color = 0xff003cca;
  paint.setColor(color);
  c.drawCircle(dot.coords.x, dot.coords.y,
    dot.maxRadius * dot.energy, paint);
    }

 if(world.state == World.GameState.Running)
  drawMessage(world.getTime(), c);
 else if(world.state == World.GameState.Ready)
  drawMessage(r.getString(R.string.ready), c);
 else if(world.state == World.GameState.Paused)
  drawMessage(r.getString(R.string.paused), c);
 else if(world.state == World.GameState.GameOver)
  drawMessage(r.getString(R.string.game_over)+
    "\n"+
    r.getString(R.string.your_time) +  " " + world.getTime() +
    "\n\n" + r.getString(R.string.game_url), c);
 }

 private void drawMessage(String message, Canvas c)
 {
  float y = paint.getTextSize();
  for(String line: message.split("\n"))
  {
  // Draw black stroke
  paint.setStrokeWidth(2F);
  paint.setColor(0xff000000);
     paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

  c.drawText(line, c.getWidth()/2F, y, paint);
  // Draw white text
  paint.setStrokeWidth(0.0F);
  paint.setColor(0xffffffff);
     paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

  c.drawText(line, c.getWidth()/2F, y, paint);

  y += paint.getTextSize();
  }
 }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
  world.state = World.GameState.Paused;
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }            
}
```

```js
package com.mickvdijke.circles;

import java.util.*;


import android.util.*;

import com.mickvdijke.circles.framework.Audio;
import com.mickvdijke.circles.framework.Game;
import com.mickvdijke.circles.framework.Graphics;
import com.mickvdijke.circles.framework.Input;
import com.mickvdijke.circles.framework.Sound;

/* I should have used pools for my objects not to make garbage
 * collector angry. As it freezes the game sometimes, 
 * I avoided some object creations. However, it doesn't help.
 */

public class World
{
 Random random = new Random();
 Game game;
 private final int DOTS_COUNT = 10;
 // In this case ArrayList is better than LinkedList:
 // list will never be resized.
 public List<Dot> dots = new ArrayList<Dot>(DOTS_COUNT);
 public Core core = new Core();
 public float offScreenRadius;
 private final float SHIELD_FACTOR = 20.0F;
 private final float ENERGY_FACTOR = 6.0F;

 private float time = 0.0F; // in seconds

 public enum GameState {Ready, Running, Paused, GameOver}

 public GameState state = GameState.Ready;

 private float difficulty = 0.04F; // Max 0.1F

 // Sounds
 // Dot collides with core
 Sound coreHurt;
 Sound coreHealth;
 Sound coreShield;
 // Dot collides with shield
 Sound shieldCollision;

 Sound gameOver;

 public World(Game game)
 {
  this.game = game;
  Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
  // Construct core
  core.coords = new VectorF((float) g.getWidth() / 2,
       (float) g.getHeight() / 2);
  core.shieldRadius = (float) g.getWidth() / 4;
  core.maxRadius = core.shieldRadius * 0.7F;
  core.angle = 0.0F;
  core.health = 1.0F;
  core.shieldEnergy = 0.0F;
  // Set offScreenRadius
  offScreenRadius = (float) Math.hypot((double) g.getWidth() / 2,
    (double) g.getHeight() / 2);
  // Max dot radius (when it's energy is 1.0F)
  Dot.maxRadius = core.maxRadius / 8.0F;
  loadSounds();
 }

 private void loadSounds()
 {
  Audio a = game.getAudio();
  coreHurt = a.newSound("core_hurt.wav");
  coreHealth = a.newSound("core_health.wav");
  coreShield = a.newSound("core_shield.wav");
  shieldCollision = a.newSound("shield_collision.wav");
  gameOver = a.newSound("game_over.wav");
 }

 // Restart the game 
 public void renew()
 {
  dots.clear();
  core.health = 1.0F;
  core.shieldEnergy = 0.0F;
  time = 0.0F;
  state = GameState.Ready;
  difficulty = 0.04F;
  generateStartDots(DOTS_COUNT);
 }
 // Add randomness
 private void generateStartDots(int count)
 {
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
   generateNewDot(true);
  }
 }

 private VectorF generateNewDotCoordsInRandomPlace()
 {
  double angle = random.nextDouble() * 2 * Math.PI;
  VectorF coords = new VectorF((float) Math.cos(angle), 
    (float) Math.sin(angle));
  coords = coords.multiply(core.shieldRadius + (offScreenRadius -
     core.shieldRadius) * random.nextFloat());
  return coords;
 }

 public void update(float deltaTime)
 {
  if(state == GameState.Ready)
   updateReady(deltaTime);
  if(state == GameState.Running)
   updateRunning(deltaTime);
  if(state == GameState.Paused)
   updatePaused(deltaTime);
  if(state == GameState.GameOver)
   updateGameOver(deltaTime);
 }

 private void doInput()
 {
     float orientAngle = game.getInput().getAzimuth();
  if(game.getInput().isTouchDown())
  {
   double touchX = (double) game.getInput().getTouchX();
   double touchY = (double) game.getInput().getTouchY();
   core.angle = 
    // Y-axis is inverted. See checkCollisionWithShield(...)
    // method
    normAngle(((float) (Math.atan2(-(touchY - core.coords.y), 
      touchX - core.coords.x) / (Math.PI * 2) *
    360.0)) - Core.GAP_ANGLE/2F);
  }
  else
  {
   core.angle = stabilizeAngle(orientAngle - Core.GAP_ANGLE/2F,
     core.angle, 8F);
  }
 }

 // Removes accelerometer noise and makes
 // core shield rotate smooth when user touches / untouches
 // the screen (and game switch accelerometer / touchscreen control).
 // Stabilisation increases, as factor value becomes larger.
 private float stabilizeAngle(float real, float current, float factor)
 {
  real = normAngle(real);
  current = normAngle(current);
  // Stabilisation should choose shortest way
  // (is it better to rotate clockwise or counterclockwise?)
  if(current - real > 180F)
   real += 360;
  if(real - current > 180F)
   real -= 360;
  // (current + current + current ... + real) / numberOfElements
  return normAngle((current * factor + real) / (factor + 1F));
 }

 private void updateReady(float deltaTime)
 {
  if(checkTouchUp() || checkMenuUp())
   state = GameState.Running;
 }
 
 private boolean checkTouchUp()
 {
  for(Input.TouchEvent event : game.getInput().getTouchEvents())
  {
   if(event.type == Input.TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP)
    return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

 private boolean checkMenuUp()
 {
  for(Input.KeyEvent event : game.getInput().getKeyEvents())
  {
   if(event.keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
   {
    if(event.type == Input.KeyEvent.KEY_UP)
     return true;
   }

  }
  return false;
 }

 private void updatePaused(float deltaTime)
 {
  if(checkTouchUp() || checkMenuUp())
   state = GameState.Running;
 }

 private void updateGameOver(float deltaTime)
 {
  if(checkTouchUp() || checkMenuUp())
   renew();
 }

 private void updateRunning(float deltaTime)
 {
  checkTouchUp(); // Just to clear touch event buffer

  if(checkMenuUp())
   state = GameState.Paused;

  countTime(deltaTime);

  doInput();

  generateNewDots(DOTS_COUNT);

  handleCollisions();
  moveDots(deltaTime);
  decreaseShieldEnergy(deltaTime);
 }

 private void decreaseShieldEnergy(float deltaTime)
 {
  if(core.shieldEnergy > 0.0F)
  {
   core.shieldEnergy -= deltaTime / SHIELD_FACTOR;
   if(core.shieldEnergy < 0.0F)
   core.shieldEnergy = 0.0F;
  }
 }

 private void generateNewDots(int neededCount)
 {
  float rand = random.nextFloat();
  if(neededCount > dots.size())
   generateNewDot(false);
 }

 private void increaseDifficulty()
 {
  difficulty += 0.00005F;
 }

 private void generateNewDot(boolean atStart)
 {
  float linearSpeed = 10.0F * difficulty;
  Dot dot = new Dot();
  if(atStart)
  {
   dot.coords = generateNewDotCoordsInRandomPlace();
  }
  else
  {
   dot.coords = generateNewDotAtOffScreenRadius();
   increaseDifficulty();
  }
  VectorF speed = new VectorF(
    linearSpeed * (-dot.coords.x / dot.coords.length()),
      linearSpeed * (-dot.coords.y / dot.coords.length()));
  dot.speed = speed;
  dot.coords.addToThis(core.coords);
  dot.energy = random.nextFloat();
  if(dot.energy <= 0.3F)
   dot.energy = 0.3F;
  float typeRand = random.nextFloat();
  Dot.Type type;
  if (typeRand >= 0.9)
   type = Dot.Type.Shield;
  else if (typeRand >= 0.8)
   type = Dot.Type.Health;
  else
   type = Dot.Type.Enemy;
  dot.type = type;
  dots.add(dot);
 }

 private void countTime(float deltaTime)
 {
  time += deltaTime;
 }

 public String getTime()
 {
  int seconds = (int) time;
  int minutes = seconds / 60;
  seconds %= 60;
  String result = "";
  if(minutes > 0)
   result += minutes + ":";
  result += String.format("%02d", seconds);
  return result;
 }

 private VectorF generateNewDotAtOffScreenRadius()
 {
  float angle = random.nextFloat() * ((float)(2 * Math.PI));
  VectorF coords =
      new VectorF(offScreenRadius * ((float) Math.cos(angle)),
     offScreenRadius * ((float) Math.sin(angle)));
  return coords;
 }
 private void moveDots(float deltaTime)
 {
  for(Dot dot : dots)
  {
   dot.coords.addToThis(dot.speed.x * deltaTime * 100.0F,
     dot.speed.y * deltaTime * 100.0F);
  }
 }

 private void handleCollisions()
 {
  Iterator<Dot> iterator = dots.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
  {
   handleCollision(iterator.next(), iterator);
  }
 }

 private void handleCollision(Dot dot, Iterator<Dot> iterator)
 {
  float lengthToCoreCenter = (float)
   Math.hypot((double)(dot.coords.x - core.coords.x),
     (double)(dot.coords.y - core.coords.y)); 
  if(Math.abs(lengthToCoreCenter - 
     core.shieldRadius) <= dot.maxRadius * dot.energy +
    Core.SHIELD_WIDTH)
   checkCollisionWithShield(dot, iterator);
  else if (lengthToCoreCenter - core.maxRadius * core.health <=
       dot.maxRadius * dot.energy)
   handleCollisionWithCore(dot, iterator);
 }

 private void checkCollisionWithShield(Dot dot, Iterator<Dot> iterator)
 {
  // I normalize (move into (0; 360) interval) angles
  // in some places. Don't know if it's needed.
  if(core.shieldEnergy > 0.0F)
  {
   iterator.remove();
   shieldCollision.play(dot.energy);
   game.getVibration().vibrate(30);
  }
  else
  {
  // Pay attention at -v.y! Y-axis is inverted, 
  // because it points downwards.
  float dotAngle = (float) Math.atan2((double) - 
    (dot.coords.y - core.coords.y),
       (double) (dot.coords.x - core.coords.x));
  dotAngle = dotAngle / (((float) Math.PI) * 2.0F) * 360.0F;
  dotAngle = normAngle(dotAngle);
  // For example, dotAngle = 3, and core.angle = 365
  // We need to solve this somehow:
  core.angle = normAngle(core.angle);
  while(dotAngle < core.angle)
  {
   dotAngle += 360.0F;
  }
  // OK, and check if dotAngle is within the gap
  if(!((dotAngle > core.angle) &&
        (dotAngle < core.angle + core.GAP_ANGLE)))
  {
   iterator.remove();
   shieldCollision.play(dot.energy);
   game.getVibration().vibrate(30);
  }
  }
 }

 private float normAngle(float angle)
 {
  float angle2 = angle;
  while(angle2 < 0.0F)
   angle2 += 360.0F;

  while(angle2 > 360.0F)
   angle2 -= 360.0F;

  return angle2;
 }

 private void handleCollisionWithCore(Dot dot, Iterator<Dot> iterator)
 {
  if(dot.type == Dot.Type.Enemy)
  {
  core.health -= dot.energy / ENERGY_FACTOR;
  if(core.health < 0.0F)
  {
   state = GameState.GameOver;
   gameOver.play(1F);
   game.getVibration().vibrate(10);
   game.getVibration().vibrate(40);
   game.getVibration().vibrate(100);
   core.health = 0.0F;
  }
  coreHurt.play(dot.energy);
  }
  else if (dot.type == Dot.Type.Health)
  {
  core.health += dot.energy / ENERGY_FACTOR;
  if(core.health > 1.0F) 
  {
   core.health = 1.0F;
  }
  coreHealth.play(dot.energy);
  }
  else if(dot.type == Dot.Type.Shield)
  {
   core.shieldEnergy += dot.energy;
   if(core.shieldEnergy > 1.0F)
    core.shieldEnergy = 1.0F;
   coreShield.play(dot.energy);
  }
  iterator.remove();
  game.getVibration().vibrate(30);
 }

}
```